# What if I use my personal @live/@gmail.com email ID as the sender ID for sending mass emails through Sendgrid?

Tags: email, outlook, sendgrid

I am planning to use Sendgrid (Email API - Essentials 100k plan) for email marketing. I am wondering if it's possible to use my `@live.com` or `@gmail.com` email address as the sender email ID, as I would rather prefer reaching out to people using my personal email, than using my personal website's one (me@mydomain.com).

The reason I am asking is because I read somewhere that email providers like outlook/gmail only allow sending a limited no. of emails to a limited no. recipients each day. Will these limits still be applicable when I use Sendgrid to send bulk emails? Or are these limits applicable just for gmail.com/outlook.com emailing platforms?

Thanks!

Comment: I think in any case limits can (and will) be imposed by your email provider. You can consult GMail help/settings to see how many e-mails you can send per day using basic account. IIRC there was number about 10000

Comment: Like 10000 per day OR per week?

Comment: No, unlock limit of email depends on Email provider. Sendgrid  can't help you to increase sending limits. You should ask Google service to help, not Sendgrid.

Comment: 10000 per day for GMail, if I remember things right

Comment: Hi @Theblank, I am not looking to increase the limits of Outlook/Gmail, I am asking if it's possible to use an email address with @gmail/@live.com domain to send bulk emails through sendgrid. I am planning of sending an email to 90,000 people in a day, only once a month. That's why, I was asking if it's possible or not to use a outlook/gmail ID as sender ID. Thanks!